# XhrRequest with reflex/reflex-dom

Tags: haskell, ghcjs, reflex

I want to perform a basic Ajax request, that's all.

I use `reflex` for the frontend and `Scotty` for the backend. The Firefox Web Console tells me the request was a success and I see the expected result there. But the website switches from `Just "default"` to `Nothing` instead of `Just "success!"`.

Here is a complete minimal example:

```
import Reflex (holdDyn)
import Reflex.Dom (button, el, mainWidget, display)
import Reflex.Dom.Xhr (performRequestAsync, xhrRequest, decodeXhrResponse)
import Reflex.Class (tag, constant)
import Data.Default (def)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  mainWidget $ el "div" $ do
    buttonEvent <- button "click me"
    let defaultReq = xhrRequest "GET" "mystring" def  --served by Scotty
    asyncEvent <- performRequestAsync (tag (constant defaultReq) buttonEvent)
    buttonDyn <- holdDyn (Just "default") $ fmap decodeXhrResponse asyncEvent
    display buttonDyn
```

and the `Scotty` part:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Web.Scotty
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Static

main = scotty 3000 $ do
  middleware $ staticPolicy (noDots >-> addBase "/mnt/b/haskell/try-reflex/hello.jsexe")
  get "/" $ do
    file "/mnt/b/haskell/try-reflex/hello.jsexe/index.html"
  get "/mystring" $ html "success!"
```

Since the debug tools tell me the request was a success, I suspect the error somewhere near `decodeXhrResponse` but I am a bit lost how I should proceed debugging since it just gets compiled to (unreadable) Javascript.

I used the try-reflex Nix script from GitHub to set up everything and compiled with `ghcjs hello.hs` in the Nix environment.

Edit: Adding the output of `curl`:

```
$ curl -G http://localhost:3000/mystring
success!%
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With help from `#reflex-frp` on freenode I found a solution: replacing `decodeXhrResponse` with `_xhrResponse_body` and using `Text` for the default string worked:

```
buttonDyn <- holdDyn (Just $ T.pack "default") $ fmap _xhrResponse_body asyncEvent
```

`decodeXhrResponse` expects some sort of JSON and although I tried to serve JSON via Scotty at one point it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simplified helper function to basically retrieve a remote URL from reflex:

```
curlGet :: MonadWidget t m => Text -> m (Event t Text)
curlGet url = do
  let req = xhrRequest "GET" url def
  pb <- getPostBuild
  asyncReq <- performRequestAsync (tag (constant req) pb)
  pure $ fmap (fromMaybe "Unknown error" . _xhrResponse_responseText) asyncReq
```