# Acess a servant server with a reflex-dom client

Tags: haskell, servant, reflex

I'm using version 0.4 of reflex-dom and I have a tiny reflex-dom client:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Reflex.Dom
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Monoid

main :: IO ()
main = mainWidget body

body :: MonadWidget t m => m ()
body  = el "div" $ do
  pb <- getPostBuild
  snd <- button "Send"
  -- Use one of the following URL's:
  let defReq = "http://localhost:8080/name/3"
  -- let defReq = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY"
  let req = XhrRequest "GET" defReq (def {_xhrRequestConfig_sendData = defReq} )
  let evReq = tagPromptlyDyn (constDyn req) snd
  evRsp <- performRequestAsync evReq
  let evResult = (result . _xhrResponse_responseText) <$> evRsp
  el "p" $ return ()
  dynText =<< holdDyn "NOPE" evResult
  return ()

result :: Show a => Maybe a -> T.Text
result (Just x) = "Received: " <> T.pack (show x)
result Nothing = "Response is Nothing"
```

As described in [XhrRequest with reflex/reflex-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264504/xhrrequest-with-reflex-reflex-dom), I'm using *_xhrResponse_responseText* and not *decodeXhrResponse*.

When I run this client with the NASA URL, it displays a nice JSON string. Therefore I assume, this reflex-dom client is working.

I have a tiny servant server too:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant
import Servant.API
import Servant.Server
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Logger       (withStdoutLogger)
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = withStdoutLogger $ \aplogger -> do
         let settings = setPort 8080 $ setLogger aplogger defaultSettings
         runSettings settings app

app :: Application
app = serve userAPI server

userAPI :: Proxy API    -- API usage:  http://localhost:8080/name/2
userAPI = Proxy

type API = "name" :> Capture "pid" Int :> Get '[PlainText] T.Text

server :: Server API
server =  name

name :: Monad m => Int ->  m T.Text
name pid = return $ nameById pid

nameById :: Int -> T.Text
nameById 1 = "Isaac Newton"
nameById 2 = "Galileo Galilei"
nameById 3 = "Marie Curie"
nameById _ = "UNKNOWN!!"
```

When I access this server in the browser with  `http://localhost:8080/name/3` or with `curl`, I see the expected result `Marie Curie`. Therefore I assume, this servant server is working.

When I run the above reflex-dom client with the URL of the localhost, I can see the request in the stdout log of the server, but the client does **NOT** display the name of *Marie Curie*. Instead the client just displays an empty string!
So as a team, the client and the server do not work together! Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are seeing Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) problems.  You can verify this (in chrome at least) by checking your browser console for an error that looks like this:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/name/3. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

If this is the case, you can enable CORS in your server by replacing this line :

```
app = serve userAPI server
```

with this line:

```
app = simpleCors (serve userAPI server)
```

You will need to import wai-cors:

```
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors
```

here is your servant server with these changes:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Servant
import Servant.API
import Servant.Server
import Network.Wai
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp
import Network.Wai.Logger       (withStdoutLogger)
import Network.Wai.Middleware.Cors
import qualified Data.Text as T

main :: IO ()
main = withStdoutLogger $ \aplogger -> do
         let settings = setPort 8080 $ setLogger aplogger defaultSettings
         runSettings settings app

app :: Application
app = simpleCors (serve userAPI server)

userAPI :: Proxy API    -- API usage:  http://localhost:8080/name/2
userAPI = Proxy

type API = "name" :> Capture "pid" Int :> Get '[PlainText] T.Text

server :: Server API
server =  name

name :: Monad m => Int ->  m T.Text
name pid = return $ nameById pid

nameById :: Int -> T.Text
nameById 1 = "Isaac Newton"
nameById 2 = "Galileo Galilei"
nameById 3 = "Marie Curie"
nameById _ = "UNKNOWN!!"
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see the error message. Using `simpleCors` however, solved the problem! I have to read about this _Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)_ stuff...