# CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing in servant

Tags: haskell, servant

using the `run` from `Network.Wai.Handler.Warp` function to server rest api

```
run :: Port -> Application -> IO ()
```

but while doing `post` request, getting an error `CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’`.
any idea how to overcome this in servant/haskell

Comment: This question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143155/acess-a-servant-server-with-a-reflex-dom-client is not exactly the same but the answer might still be the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`wai-cors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wai-cors-0.2.6/docs/Network-Wai-Middleware-Cors.html) middleware to add CORS headers.

At the end you'll have something like

```hs
app = simpleCors $ serve api serverImpl
```

where

- `simpleCors` is a `Middleware` from `wai-cors`
- `serve` turns servant handlers into `wai` `Application`
- `api :: Proxy YourAPI`
- `serverImpl` is your handlers' implementation